# Comparison of code behavior with a database

Tags: database

I am trying to start a project, the main goal of which is to produce a software that compares written code to a specific database and need identifying the type of software developer I might need.

So what the software will do, is it will analyze the code of another software (let's say written in java code), to which it has access, and will trie to understand its behavior and check this behavior against behaviors or characteristics in the data base. So it is not comparing code to code, but rather if the code achieves the behavior, through whatever means, described in the database. How would you go to solve this issue? Would it involve someone proficient in compilers, so the software behavior is understood through some special type of compiler? Machine learning specialist? Compare the code behavior with database down on the bitcode level? I know there are several softwares out there that scan your Android app, decompile it to see what libraries you are using. I am guessing the idea would work in a similar way, the main difference is, in case of libraries, the code explicitly says what library it is using, while in this case, the software needs to understand the behavior of the code.

My goal is to find a software developer that could help me solve this issue, so that I can work on the project with him/her, just need to know what I am searching for. As you might have guessed from the broad description above, I myself, am not a developer.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I think your first step is to write a much better set of requirements than appear in the question. At the very least you need to specify an example of what sort of behaviour or 'characteristic' you are interested in. Without some more clues than you have given you're not going to get very far.

Comment: So I can give an example of what I have in mind. One application would be software patents. So this software would allow to scan your code and compare its behavior (its end goal after compilation) to the data base of patents. So we are talking about a very large number of different types of behaviour

Answer (score 0):

> How would you go to solve this issue?

Personally, I wouldn't even try.

> Would it involve someone proficient in compilers, so the software
>   behavior is understood through some special type of compiler?

A Compiler doesn't do anything like that (apart from tokenising the code but that's only a start), so no.

> Machine learning specialist?

This is a possibility, but only a start.

> Compare the code behavior with database down on the bitcode level?

That doesn't even make sense.

For your requirements, if I started at all I'd go for someone involved in AI Research. I don't believe that it would be at all possible to do what you want unless it was either trivial (i.e. you have a patent for HTML Links and a link in code is trivial to find) or you use some extremely advanced techniques which are unlikely to be found outside an AI Lab.

For a start, you have to work out how the represent the patent in a way that can be understood by a program. The description on the Patent will not do.